# Convert "yymm" numeric to months since 9101 (Jan 1991)

Tags: r

I have a data set that runs from 1991-01 to 1996-12 in R. In order to calculate some time-dependent metrics on some of the data set, I am trying to have a "months since first entry" column. To do so I need to convert a number like 9107 into 07, 9207 into 12+7=19, and 9301 into 12+12+1=25. Ie, the first two digits specify a full year (12 months), and the last two digits specify months since January (01). How would I go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: is the date column already in this four digit format (9107)?

Comment: yes, it is, in fact

Comment: so `9101` is `1` and `9301` is `24` is a bit strange, better would be `9101` is `0` or `9301` equals `25`

Comment: The 9301 should be 25 if we do the same logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be, we can use `substr` (splitted in multiple lines for more clarity and also `as.integer`)

```
yrs <- as.integer(substr(v1, 1, 2))
mths <- as.integer(substr(v1, 3, 4))
mths[mths == 1] <- 0
12 * (yrs - yrs[1]) + mths
#[1]  7 19 24
```

---

Or without `substr`

```
yrs <- v1 %/% 100
12 * (yrs - yrs[1]) + (v1 %% 100)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(9107, 9207, 9301)
```

Comment: why you are using `cumsum`?

Comment: @petres In the OP's post, it is `12 + 7`, so I guess he needs to do cumulative

Comment: `cumsum((9201 - 9100) %% 12)` gives `5`

Comment: @petres you are right.  The OP updated with more details, so I changed it

Answer (score 0):

Using the `substr`ings.

```
(as.numeric(substr(x, 2, 2)) - 1)*12 + as.numeric(substr(x, 3, 4)) - 1
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
# [24] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
# [47] 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68
# [70] 69 70 71
```

I believe, 9101 should be 0, since it is the distance of itself.

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c(9101, 9102, 9103, 9104, 9105, 9106, 9107, 9108, 9109, 9110, 
9111, 9112, 9201, 9202, 9203, 9204, 9205, 9206, 9207, 9208, 9209, 
9210, 9211, 9212, 9301, 9302, 9303, 9304, 9305, 9306, 9307, 9308, 
9309, 9310, 9311, 9312, 9401, 9402, 9403, 9404, 9405, 9406, 9407, 
9408, 9409, 9410, 9411, 9412, 9501, 9502, 9503, 9504, 9505, 9506, 
9507, 9508, 9509, 9510, 9511, 9512, 9601, 9602, 9603, 9604, 9605, 
9606, 9607, 9608, 9609, 9610, 9611, 9612)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help1

Comment: Very welcome @FZ1712, please mark an answer as accepted, help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: I am quite sure that in your solution `9301` isn't `24` as it was asked for, @FZ1712 please correct your question